# Checkbox is not disabled after checking other checkbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, checkbox

I have 2 checkboxes:

```
<div>
    <input type="checkbox" id="dx_article_excerpt">
    <label for="dx_article_excerpt">
        <?php _e( 'Displayyyyyyyy Excerpt', 'dxeasypb' ); ?>
    </label>
</div>
<div>
    <input type="checkbox" id="dx_article_content">
    <label for="dx_article_content">
        <?php _e( 'Display Content', 'dxeasypb' ); ?>
    </label>
</div>
```

I want when the first is clicked, the content checkbox to be disabled automatically. I've tried the following thing:

```
if (document.getElementById('dx_article_excerpt').checked) {
    document.getElementById("dx_article_content").disabled = true;
}
```

But guess what.. it's not working.

Comment: use radio button it is made for this kind of function

Answer (score 1):

**Why is not working?**

1. Because no event is there .assign `onchange` event

   `onchange="change()"`
2. Wrap the js inside the function

**Updated with toggle**

```js
function change(){
        document.getElementById("dx_article_content").disabled = document.getElementById('dx_article_excerpt').checked;
}
```

```html
<div><input type="checkbox" id="dx_article_excerpt" onchange="change()"><label for="dx_article_excerpt"><?php _e( 'Displayyyyyyyy Excerpt', 'dxeasypb' ); ?></label></div>
<div><input type="checkbox" id="dx_article_content"><label for="dx_article_content"><?php _e( 'Display Content', 'dxeasypb' ); ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use click event to change the content check status as below snippet using jquery :

```js
$(function() {
  $("#dx_article_excerpt").click(function(){
     $("#dx_article_content").prop("disabled",this.checked);
  })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div><input type="checkbox" id="dx_article_excerpt"><label for="dx_article_excerpt">first</label></div>
<div><input type="checkbox" id="dx_article_content"><label for="dx_article_content">content</label></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
$(".checkbox").change(function() {
  $(".checkbox").not(this).prop("disabled", $(this).is(":checked"))
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div><input type="checkbox" id="dx_article_excerpt" class="checkbox"><label for="dx_article_excerpt">1</label></div>
<div><input type="checkbox" id="dx_article_content" class="checkbox"><label for="dx_article_content">2</label></div>
```

1. Add a class for both checkbox.
2. Use the status of current checkbox changed to prop disabled of the other checkbox

Comment: @RumenPanchev did you add the class to both checkbox?